# Como utilizar root.after() en tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Al generar una label en tkinter que me indica que el usuario fue ingresado con exito, utilizo root.after antes de generar el top level, pero incluso estando debajo del label.pack() el retraso ourre antes de mostrar la etiqueta

```
def userValidation(event): 
"Validar usuario con la base de datos correspondiente"  
global labelUser, user
destroyLabelUser()
user=entryUser.get()
user=user.replace("'","-")
entryUser.delete(0,"end")
cursor=conn.cursor()
query=f"Select ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='{user}'"
cursor.execute(query)
if len(cursor.fetchone())==1: #Autenticacion en base de datos
    cursor.close()
    labelUserFont=font.Font(family="Helvetica",weight="bold",size=35)
    labelUser=tk.Label(root,text="Usuario valido",bg="Green",font=labelUserFont)
    labelUser.pack(fill="x")
    createTicket()
    root.after(1500,dataEntry())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenidx a StackOverflow! c:

Tu problema se debe a que estás diciéndole a Python que ejecute la función usando los `()`. Esto hace que la función se ejecute inmediatamente antes de establecer el after.

Por lo tanto, la solución es simplemente esta:

```
root.after(1500, dataEntry)
```

Notese que no usé los parentesis. Sin los parentesis, le estás diciendo a Python que quieres pasar como argumento a la función en si.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahi me funciono, jamas pense q eso afectaria!