# Porque ejecuta el proceso antes de iniciar la aplicación?

Tags: python, tkinter, argparse

Hola recuerdan la pregunta anterior de la terminal y pasarle argumentos bueno hice la interfaz y no funciona

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def ExecuteTerminalCommand(DT):
    proceso = Popen(DT, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proceso.communicate()
    print(stdout, stderr)

Ter = Tk()

InBox = Text()
PDT = InBox.get(1.0,END)
InBox.bind('<Return>', ExecuteTerminalCommand(PDT))
InBox.pack()
Ter.mainloop()
```

cuando lo ejecuto me da este error

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programacion\Python\Kife> & C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Programacion/Python/Kife/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programacion\Python\Kife\Main.py", line 14, in <module>
    InBox.bind('<Return>', ExecuteTerminalCommand(PDT))
  File "c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programacion\Python\Kife\Main.py", line 6, in ExecuteTerminalCommand
    proceso = Popen(DT, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__        
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child 
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

para probar estoy utilizando una CLI que diseñe este es su código por si les interesa

```
import argparse

Parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy file content to another file')
Parser.add_argument('source')
Parser.add_argument('dest')

args = Parser.parse_args()

with open(args.source, 'rb') as source:
    Content = source.read()

with open(args.dest, 'wb') as dest:
    dest.write(Content)
```

No so que es lo que ejecuta mal porque hasta que se presione el Enter en el Textbox no deberia ejecutar nada entonces que es?

Comment: Me funciono muchas gracias son un grande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De hecho tu función SI se está ejecutando en cuanto inicias el programa. Por que sucede este comportamiento no deseado? Por que cuando pones paréntesis a la derecha del nombre de una función le dices a Python que quieres ejecutarla. La solución a tu problema en este caso sería usar un lambda, que es una función anónima pequeña y acepta comandos de una línea. Recuerda que un bind espera que le pases un objeto funcion.

La llamada a tu función debería de quedar así: `lambda event:ExecuteTerminalCommand(PDT)`. Recuerda además que cuando una función enlazada con bind se llama, debe poder recibir un argumento, que será un objeto con información sobre el evento que llamó a dicha función.

Más información sobre usar una función anonima (lambda) en Tkinter en estas preguntas:

- [Como utilizar root.after() en tkinter python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436470/como-utilizar-root-after-en-tkinter-python/436472#436472)
- [Como llamar a función con parámetros diferentes con botones dinámicos con tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457264/como-llamar-a-funci%c3%b3n-con-par%c3%a1metros-diferentes-con-botones-din%c3%a1micos-con-tkinte/457271#457271)
- [No puedo almacenar valor del Entry](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469646/no-puedo-almacenar-valor-del-entry/469654#469654)